# How can I combine three ASP MVC routes into one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes set up:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "content_article",
            "A{rk}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Server", action = "Article" },
            new { rk = @"^[\dA-Z]{3}$" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "content_contentBlock",
            "C{rk}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Server", action = "ContentBlock" },
            new { rk = @"^[\dA-Z]{3}$" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "content_favoritesList",
            "F{rk}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Server", action = "FavoritesList" },
            new { rk = @"^[\dA-Z]{3}$" }
        );
```

Is there a way that I could combine:

```
"A{rk}/{title}",
"C{rk}/{title}",
"F{rk}/{title}",
```

into one single route with an action of Index that's taken if the URL starts with an A, C or F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want just one route to cover all three and to point to `Index` action? If that's the question than the answer is

### Sure you can

You just have to change your regular expression a little to this route definition:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "content",
    "{lrk}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Server", action = "Index" },
    new { lrk = @"^[ACF][0-9A-Z]{3}$" }
);
```

And that's it. Parsing of the first letter out is then done by Index action that would likely (and hopefully) execute an appropriate separate method.

```
public ActionResult Index(string lrk)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lrk))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("lrk")
    }
    char first = lrk[0];
    switch(first)
    {
        case 'A':
            return GetArticle(lrk.Substring(1));
        case 'C':
            return GetContent(lrk.Substring(1));
        case 'F':
            return GetFavorites(lrk.Substring(1));
        default:
            return View();
    }
}

private ActionResult GetArticle(string rk)
{
    ...
}

// and other couple
```

As you can see the three methods have the same signature as if they were controller actions, but they're not, since they're `private`. You can either set them as `private` or decorathe them with `NonActionAttribute` so they can't get picked up by your default route, that you likely have as well...

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can still have three routes, but simplify definition of them by adding extension method for RouteCollection :

```
public class ActionMap : Dictionary<string, string>
    {}

    public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, ActionMap map)
        {
            if(!url.Contains("{action}")) throw new ArgumentException("{action} segment is required", url);

            foreach (var actionKey in map.Keys)
            {
                string routeName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", name, map[actionKey]);
                string routeUrl = url.Replace("{action}", actionKey);
                var routeDefaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults);
                routeDefaults["action"] = map[actionKey];

                Route route = new Route(routeUrl, new MvcRouteHandler())
                {
                    Defaults = routeDefaults,
                    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),
                    DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
                };

                routes.Add(routeName, route);
            }
        }
    }
```

And now definition of those routes looks like :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                    "content",
                   "{action}{rk}/{title}",
                   new { controller = "Server" },
                   new { rk = @"^[\dA-Z]{3}$" },
                    new ActionMap { { "a", "Article" }, { "c", "ContentBlock" }, { "f", "FavoritesList" } }
            );
```

Also you can reuse it for another similar situations. Hope this helps